# Is my argument true : prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}\sim\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, asymptotics

Let $f\geq 0$ continuous and integrable over $[0,\infty [$ and $g\geq 0$ continuous and bounded $\geq 0$ over $[0,\infty [$. Let $\lambda >0$. Set $$\varphi(\lambda )=\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}.$$

Prove that $$\varphi(\lambda )\sim_{\lambda \to \infty }\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f.$$

---

Can I do as following : Since $g$ is bounded,

$$g(x)=\mathcal O(1),$$
and thus $$\lambda +g(x)=\lambda +\mathcal O(1)=\lambda \left(1+\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)\right)=\lambda (1+o(1)).$$
Therefore $$\frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{f}{\lambda \left(1+o(1)\right)}=\frac{f}{\lambda} \left(1+o(1)\right),$$
and thus $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty f+o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f\right),$$
and thus $$\varphi(\lambda )\sim_{\lambda \to \infty }\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty f.$$

Is it working ?

---

**Added**

We have when $\lambda \to \infty $ that $$\frac{f}{\lambda+g}=\frac{f}{\lambda} + o\left(\frac{f}{\lambda }\right).$$
I set $R(\lambda,x )=o\left(\frac{f(x)}{\lambda }\right)$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. There is $M>0$ s.t. $$|R(\lambda,x )|\leq \varepsilon\frac{f}{\lambda },$$
when $\lambda \geq M$. Then $$\int_0^\infty |R(x,\lambda )|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx,$$
and thus $$\int_0^\infty R(x,\lambda )\,dx = o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty  f(x)\,dx\right).$$

Comment: The argument is obviously wrong, for example when you replace a big-O by a little-o, and much too vague, for example when you integrate a little-o on an unbounded interval. For a proof, simply use $$\lambda\leqslant\lambda+g\leqslant\lambda+C$$ for some given finite $C$ and integrate.

Comment: @Did: Yes sorry. I changed the argument. Is it correct now ?

Comment: Too vague again.

Comment: @Did: Could you please tell me what is not correct ? That would help me a lot, because unfortunately, I don't see why this argument is not correct.

Comment: As already mentioned, integrating some little-o term on some unbounded interval (or even a nonuniform little-o term on a bounded interval) can lead to surprises. Exercise: Find some regular functions $h_n$ such that $h_n(x)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, for every $x$ in $[0,1]$ (that is, $h_n(x)=o(1)$, right?), and $\int_0^1h_n(x)dx$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: The thing is that in my book, it's said that for example, if $f(x)=1+x+x^2+o(x^2)$ then $\int_0^t f(x)dx=F(0)+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+o(t^3).$ So this is not correct ? I don't really see the difference between this example and what I did previously (sorry). @Did

Comment: You need an estimate for $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$, where do you see one in the results you recalled?

Comment: In my answer, I proved why is it a little o (in **added**). It doesn't work ? But I still don't understand why I needed all that, since it's straightforward (but I don't understand the subtlety)... May be you could explain ? Moreover, I'm still on your $h_n(x)=o(1)$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_0^1 h_n(x)dx\neq 0$. But even, here, it's different, no ? To finish, as you seem to suppose, if $f(x)=1+x+x^2+o(x^3)$ then $\int_0^x f(t)dt =t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+o(t^3)$ is wrong, but I don't understand why (since I always used this...)@Did

Comment: Peter: **Please read what I wrote** instead of imagining things. Where would I have written that $f(x)=1+x+x^2+o(x^2)$ (hence, a typo in your comment) would not imply $\int_0^tf(x)dx=t+t^2/2+t^3/3+o(t^3)$? "why I needed all that, since it's straightforward" What is "all that"? Yes there is a straightforward proof, **as indicated in my first comment**...

Comment: @Did: Yes, I finally understood your comment (thank you and sorry for my question, I'm a little novice). But is what I added in my original post wrong ?(in the part **Added**).

Comment: Very first step: why do you know that $$\frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{f}{\lambda }+o\left(\frac{f}{\lambda }\right)\ ?$$ See, we can't really know why you assert this, randomly or for some good reasons...

Comment: Because $$g=O(1)\implies \lambda +g=\lambda +O(1)=\lambda \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)\right)=\lambda \left(1+o_{\lambda \to\infty }\left(1\right)\right).$$ Now $$\frac{f}{g+\lambda }=f\left(\frac{1}{\lambda (1+o(1))}\right) =\frac{f}{\lambda }\left(1+o(1)\right),$$ and since $\frac{1}{1+o(1)}=1+o(1)$ we get $$\frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{f}{\lambda }\left(1+o(1)\right)=\frac{f}{\lambda }+\frac{f}{\lambda }o\left(1\right)=\frac{f}{\lambda }+f\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right). \tag{E}$$

Comment: Now since $f$ is integrable, we get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f+\left(\int_0^\infty f\right)o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)$$ and since $\int_0^\infty f$ is finite, we get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f+o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f\right).$$ Does it work now ? @Did

Comment: As I said already, either you know the reasons why this holds (that $g$ is bounded) and then you could as well use this condition from the start, or you do not, and then such strings of characters can lead you into chaos. IOW, if you want a clean proof, drop the os and Os and work with inequalities valid on (0,oo)...

Comment: @Did : it's in the hypothesis : $g$ is bounded and continuous on $[0,\infty [$. So it should work, no ? By the way, $fo\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)=o\left(\frac{f}{\lambda }\right)$ should also work since $f$ doesn't depend on $\lambda $, no ? I really want to use $o$ and $O$ since it's new for me, and I want to practice with them

Comment: "So it should work, no ?" Exactly the problem... You should know whether "it works" or not, you should be deadly certain about it, and not stay in the mist forever... For example, it is most disquieting to read that you wrote "since $g$ is bounded and continuous" since this mixes the property which, through a careful argument, indeed leads to the conclusion (the property that $g$ is bounded) to an irrelevant property of $g$ (being continuous).

Comment: @Did: The fact that $g$ is continuous allow us to prove that $\varphi(\lambda )=\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}$ is well defined for all $\lambda $. So it's relevant. Moreover, if I was totally sure about my argument, I wouldn't post my question here. Sorry If I get you mad, it was not my aim. I only want to understand better (and unfortunately, I more lost than before). May be you could have the kindness to tell me if my 3 last post make sense and if the proof is correct ? I guess you do math since many years, so it's normal that for you thing are obvious. I just started 6 month ago alone

Comment: "The fact that g is continuous allow us to prove that... is well defined" Thus, it is irrelevant to the argument you were presenting when you invoked it. "Sorry If I get you mad" Huh, what? "May be you could have the kindness to..." Which three last posts?

Comment: Since $g$ is bounded , $g(x)=O(1)$, therefore $$\lambda +g(x)=\lambda +O(1)\implies\lambda +g(x)= \lambda (1+O(1/\lambda ))=\lambda (1+o(1))$$ and thus $$\frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{f}{\lambda(1+o(1)) }=\frac{f}{\lambda }(1+o(1))$$ since $\frac{1}{1+o(1)}=1+o(1)$. Therefore $$\frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\frac{f}{\lambda }+\frac{f}{\lambda }o(1)=\frac{f}{\lambda }+ f o(\frac{1}{\lambda })\tag{*}.$$ Then $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{g+\lambda }=\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f+\left(\int_0^\infty  f\right) o(1/\lambda )=\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f+ o\left(1/\lambda \int_0^\infty f\right).$$ @Did

Comment: **Q1)** First is my previous post correct for you ? **Q2)**  for $(*)$ I would like to say $$\frac{f}{\lambda }+\frac{f}{\lambda }o(1)=\frac{f}{\lambda }+o(\frac{f}{\lambda }),$$ is it correct ? **Q3)** and thus by integration we get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda }+\int_0^\infty o(\frac{f}{\lambda })=\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda }+o\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda }\right)$$ and it's here where there is a problem ? (many thanks for all your time) @Did

Comment: Q1) Too many posts, I do not know. Q2) For each fixed $x$, yes. Q3) Yes there is a problem, one of uniformity, as already explained.

Comment: @Did: Thank you. For **Q1)**, I was only talking about the following post : Since g is bounded , $g(x)=O(1)$, therefore
$$λ+g(x)=λ+O(1)⟹λ+g(x)=λ(1+O(1/λ))=λ(1+o(1))$$
and thus
$\frac{f}{λ+g}=\frac{f}{λ}(1+o(1))=\frac{f}{λ}(1+o(1))$
since $\frac{1}{1+o(1)}=1+o(1)$. Therefore
$$\frac{f}{λ}+g=\frac{f}{λ}+\frac{f}{λ}o(1)=\frac{f}{λ}+fo(\frac{1}{λ}).$$
Then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{g+λ}=\frac{1}{λ}\int_0^\infty f+\left(\int_0^\infty f\right)o(\frac{1}{λ})=\frac{1}{λ}∫_0^\infty f+o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f\right).$$ Is it correct ?

Comment: No -- as already explained, for the reason already mentioned.

Comment: Could you please tell me which step is not correct ? Because I really don't see. I suppose it's correct until $$\frac{f}{λ}+g=\frac{f}{λ}+\frac{f}{λ}o(1)=\frac{f}{λ}+fo(\frac{1}{λ}).$$
And it gets wrong when I integrate, i.e. at
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{g+λ}=\frac{1}{λ}\int_0^\infty f+\left(\int_0^\infty f\right)o(\frac{1}{λ})=\frac{1}{λ}∫_0^\infty f+o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f\right).$$ I guess the problem come from $\left(\int_0^\infty f\right) o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)=o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty f\right)$, no ? @Did

Comment: I find your claim in the final edit (the one that starts with "There is M>0 s.t...." not properly justified. The main criticism with the type of proof you seem hellbent on making is that any *complete* proof (i.e. which contains all necessary justifications) of that form will necessarily *contain* the simpler proofs you've been recommended. It will also, then, contain a lot of unnecessary parts and be significantly less clear.

Comment: "I guess the problem come from..." I guess the problem comes from your blind adherence to notations you do not understand and from your refusal to "look under the hood" at what these really mean. Anyway, sorry but at this point, "the problem" has been explained and reexplained to you, so...

Comment: @AntonioVargas: If $R(x,\lambda )=o\left(\frac{f(x)}{\lambda }\right)$ when $\lambda \to \infty $, doesn't it mean that there is $M$ s.t. $|R(x,\lambda )|\leq \varepsilon\frac{f(x)}{\lambda }$ when $\lambda >M$ ?

Comment: I just saw briefly the post, I think a problem is when you right $g(x)=O(1)$ when $\lambda \to \infty $ since $g$ doesn't depend of $\lambda $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists some $M$ such that, for every $x\geq 0$, $0\leq g(x)\leq M$.

For any $x$, $\displaystyle \left|\frac{1}{\lambda +g(x)}-\frac{1}{\lambda } \right|= \frac{g(x)}{\lambda(\lambda+g(x))}\leq \frac {g(x)}{\lambda^2}\leq \frac M{\lambda^2}$

Thus $$
\left|\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f}{\lambda +g}-\frac{f}{\lambda }\right|\leq \int_0^{\infty}f\left|\frac{1}{\lambda +g}-\frac{1}{\lambda } \right|\leq \frac{M}{\lambda^2}\int_0^{\infty}f$$

Hence $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f}{\lambda +g}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f}{\lambda } + O\left( \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f}{\lambda } + o\left( \frac{1}{\lambda}\right)$$

Comment: at your last equality, is it correct that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda }+o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f}{\lambda }+o\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\int_0^\infty  f\right)$$ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes. In general, if $c\neq 0$ is a constant and $g(x)$ is a function, $o(cg(x)) = o(g(x))$. This is very easy to prove if you go back to the definition of little-o.