# If $f(x)=o(g(x))$ prove that $\int_a^x f(t)dt=C+o\left(\int_a^x g(t)dt\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I have a big doubt. @Did gave me a doubts in his comment in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855540/is-my-argument-true-prove-that-int-0-infty-fracf-lambda-g-sim-frac1).

Is it true that (if $f$ and $g$ are integrable), that $$f(x)=o(g(x))\implies \int_a^t f(x)dx=o\left(\int_a^t g(x)dx\right) \ \ ?$$

For me it was always true since for example

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+o(x)\implies \ln(1+t)=\int_0^t\frac{1}{1+x}dx=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2).$$

Now I tried to prove it as :

---

Suppose $f(x)=o_{x=0}(g(x))$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. There is $\delta>0$ s.t. $$|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|\leq \varepsilon|g(x)|,$$
and thus,  $$|t|<\delta\implies \int_0^t|f(x)|dx\leq \varepsilon \int_0^t |g(x)|dx.$$

Unfortunately, I only get $$\int_0^t|f(x)|dx=o\left(\int_0^t |g(x)|dx\right),$$
but not 
$$\int_0^t f(x)dx=o\left(\int_0^t g(x)dx\right),$$
so maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: Are you assuming that $g$ is nonnegative? Because, as you know, $f=o(g)$ is strictly equivalent to $|f|=o(|g|)$...

Comment: @Did: thank you for all your answers :) In fact, I don't know that $g$ is non negative.

Comment: Then the integrals of $g$ might be too small, due to some cancellations between parts where $g>0$ and parts where $g<0$.

Comment: @Did : so it doesn't work. Thank you, that really help :)

Comment: No it does not. BTW, why the completely illogical $C$?

Comment: @Did: indeed, it's a mistakes.

Comment: @Did: Sorry to ask you that, but could you please have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856790/compute-lim-h-to-0fte-pt-left-frace-ht-1h-rightdt). I won't ask you in a post to answer to an other post in the future, but since it's more or less related to what we talked yesterday, I would enjoy to have your opinion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is non negative then as $\left| \int_0^t f \right| \leq \int_0^t |f|$ then you obtain your result.

If it is not the case consider for example:

- $f(x)=x^{1+\alpha} \left| \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right|$
- $g(x)=x \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Then for $\alpha >0$, $f(x)=o(g(x))$.

More over:
$$\int_0^t g(x) dx =\int_\frac{1}{t}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u^3} du$$
$$\int_0^t f(x) dx =\int_\frac{1}{t}^\infty \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{3+\alpha}} du$$
to estimate the integrals notice that:
$$\int_{k \pi}^{(k+1) \pi} \frac{\sin(u)}{u^3}=(-1)^k\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(s)}{(k \pi+s)^3} du$$
so:
$$\int_\frac{1}{t}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u^3} \sim 2\sum_{k =\frac{1}{\pi t}}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k \pi)^3}$$

Similarly, as:
$$\int_{k \pi}^{(k+1) \pi} \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{3+\alpha}}=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(s)}{(k \pi+s)^{3+\alpha}} du$$
we have:
$$\int_\frac{1}{t}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u^3} \sim 2\sum_{k =\frac{1}{\pi t}}^\infty \frac{1}{(k \pi)^{3+\alpha}}$$

Now as the first series is an alternating series and the second one a Riemann series you can show that:
$$\left|\int_0^t g(x) dx \right| \leq C t^3$$
$$\left|\int_0^t f(x) dx \right| \geq c t^{2+\alpha}$$
so wuth any $\alpha < 1$ you obtain a counterexample.